# Multimeter shows 50 M Ω between 9V battery terminals. Why so high?

Tags: resistance, multimeter, short-circuit, ohms, ohmmeter

I'm using my digital multimeter to measure the resistance between the terminals of a 9 volt battery i had lying around.

Why does it read as 50 M Ω? Why is the resistance so high?  I would think that the resistance in the battery would be 0 (zero) or close to it because if I ran a wire between the terminals to short them out, that WOULD short out the battery, which makes me think that there would be very little resistance between the terminals.  I hope that makes sense?

And I would think that with such a high resistance - 50 M Ω - that even with a wire between the terminals, the battery wouldn't short.

Comment: If the resistance between the two terminals was 0R, then you would never be able to store charge

Answer (score 9):

A multimeter measures resistance by applying a voltage between its probes, and measuring the resulting current (or applies current and measures the voltage), so any reading you get when measuring across a power source, or across a component in a powered circuit, is meaningless.

NEVER try to measure resistance in a powered circuit.

Comment: Note that you might easily damage your multimeter that way.

Comment: @MarcusMüller You and Peter and Ryan have pointed out a scenario that any *quality multimeter* should be able to pass. Be very wary of any multimeter that include **current scales** on its main scale switch - its fuse should have easy access ;-)

Comment: @glen_geek indeed :) But anyway, it's pretty easy to damage even a 10A-fused current sensing path of a multimeter with household-grade AA batteries!

Comment: NEVER try to measure resistance in a powered circuit, gee I wonder how everybody figures out source impedance. Unless there is a method to safely measure resistance in a powered circuit, but that would mean your answer is wrong... no way!